# Using Swagger in Web API to provide metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have created the Web API which accepts input parameter and returns the JSON result. Since we are not able to use the Web API in adding the web reference
[image]
I tried to install the Swagger UL for .Net and Swashbuckle-Swagger for WebAPI from the Nugget Package.Now when try to debug the application `http://localhost:24417/` it throws error saying

`Method 'GetDocumentation' in type 'Swagger.Net.XmlCommentDocumentationProvider' from assembly 'Swagger.Net, Version=0.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation. 
  Line 38:                 throw new Exception("Please enable \"XML documentation file\" in project properties with default (bin\\TGSSampleData.XML) value or edit value in App_Start\\SwaggerNet.cs");`

I tried to enable 
[image]
But still throws the same error. Also can anyone please tell how will we be calling the endpoint from the browser. Earlier before swagger I use to call like `http://localhost:46151/api/TGSData?ROOM=KOMP2&DOB_GT=01-05&DOB_LT=30-DEC-06&STATUS_TYPE=CMPLT` and it will return the JSON result. Please help me with this

Comment: Last link is an local address. we cannot see it.

Comment: @pcbabu yes I just gave it show how my API endpoint looks like.

Comment: This should look like `https://localhost:46151/swagger/ui/index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is self explanatory from the throw message `Please enable \"XML documentation file\" in project properties with default (bin\TGSanokeData.XNK) value or edit value in App_Start\Swaggernet.cs");`

You can do change in in the XML file or or call `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger` and `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwaggerUI`to set proper values. These are not related to swagger. These are configuration settings related issues.

Comment: I am not sure what value we will be setting there

Comment: All the samples shows after installation of the Swagger it takes to the swagger page navigating to https://localhost:46151/swagger Please help me with this

Comment: Found the issue I installed both Swagger for .Net

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't follow up. What was the issue? Just for tacking.